# Is there a way to load a tile map (like google or bing) into Qgis, of a certain year?

Tags: qgis

I am loading a google map into qgis 3.6. I don't want to see the lastest map, but (if it exists) I want to load an older map, that I have seen in google earth. Is there a way to make the choice?

when I load an xyz tile I use this reference (for google satellite):

```
https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

Is there some attribute I can add or modify to the link? Thank you!